# HttpPost android multiple entities

Tags: java, android, http

I am trying to use `MultipartEntityBuilder` to set some entities in my httpPost in Android.
I downloaded `httpmime-4.3.jar` and I added it to Eclipse in my lib folder. But when I execute this code:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addTextBody("PARAMS", "telo");
httpPost.setEntity(entity.build());
```

It produces this error:

```
07-30 18:21:00.172: E/AndroidRuntime(3150): FATAL EXCEPTION: AudioRecorder Thread
07-30 18:21:00.172: E/AndroidRuntime(3150): Process: com.example.telo, PID: 3150
07-30 18:21:00.172: E/AndroidRuntime(3150): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
07-30 18:21:00.172: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.addTextBody(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:126)
07-30 18:21:00.172: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at org.gradiant.serverCom.SendAudioToServer.POST(SendAudioToServer.java:58)
07-30 18:21:00.172: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at com.example.telo.MainActivity.onFrameAcquired(MainActivity.java:133)
07-30 18:21:00.172: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at org.gradiant.audioAcquisition.AudioCapture.record(AudioCapture.java:113)
07-30 18:21:00.172: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at org.gradiant.audioAcquisition.AudioCapture.access$0(AudioCapture.java:88)
07-30 18:21:00.172: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at org.gradiant.audioAcquisition.AudioCapture$1.run(AudioCapture.java:79)
07-30 18:21:00.172: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you also need this jar:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2

Please note that you may wish to consider using something like gradle or maven to manage your builds.  This way you can simply say which dependency  you want and maven or gradle will automatically download load it for you and make it available on your classpath within your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to set your content-type and then add it to the entity. Try something like this:

```
File f = new File(Your_file_path);

        FileBody bd = new FileBody(f);
        FormBodyPart fbp = new FormBodyPart("file", bd);
        fbp.addField("Content-Type", "audio/mp4");

         entity.addPart(fbp);
```